# Change vector color in button drawable left

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am unable to change the color of my vector used in my button widget.

Below is my code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search"
    android:background="@color/blueButton"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:tint="@color/white"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

By adding tint, it is still showing me below result:
[image]

Here is the vector code:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M15.5,14h-0.79l-0.28,-0.27C15.41,12.59 16,11.11 16,9.5 16,5.91 13.09,3 9.5,3S3,5.91 3,9.5 5.91,16 9.5,16c1.61,0 3.09,-0.59 4.23,-1.57l0.27,0.28v0.79l5,4.99L20.49,19l-4.99,-5zM9.5,14C7.01,14 5,11.99 5,9.5S7.01,5 9.5,5 14,7.01 14,9.5 11.99,14 9.5,14z"/>
```

Comment: Is it a vector drawable? Show its code

Comment: @Xenolion I added the code.

Comment: Check the answer

Comment: Sorry I got offline!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `android:drawableTint` instead of `android:tint`.

Comment: Worked like Charm!

Comment: There is an issue, this only worked at API 23 and above. What to do for below?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 android:fillColor="#FF000000"
```

To:

```
 android:fillColor="@color/white"
```

Comment: No,I want to change it from Button XML. Because, if I want to use same search vector with diff colors in other layouts, then this will lead me to create more xml vectors with different colors.

Comment: @ben-p solved it. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46942521/7746337

Comment: Oooh I got it! All the best! I didnt know such an attribute exists. Lemme give him an upvote for really!

Comment: If you encounter any issue refer to here https://github.com/snodnipper/android-appcompat-issue198613 and also https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37077118 but its a bit old may be already solved! **Happy coding!**

Comment: I will must take a look :) and gave you a +1 because your way is right somehow.